# wicked_pdf, Unable to render pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf using wicked_pdf although getting an error 'Unable to render template'. I have followed the wicked_pdf guide but I'm getting stuck. Any help is appreciated.

url:

```
http://localhost:3000/app/letters/1.pdf
```

app/controllers/app/letters_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.pdf do
     render pdf: "Letters"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
    end
    end
  end
```

Show page link:

```
<li><a href="<%= app_letter_path(@letter, format: :pdf) %>" target="_blank"> Print</a></li>
```

app/views/app/letters/show.pdf:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Error:

Failed to load PDF document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options) Checkout here for available options

1. Create a layout for pdf document in `views/layouts/pdf.html.erb`

> ```
>   <!DOCTYPE html>
>   <html>
>     <head>
>       <title>My PDF</title>
>       <%#= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "style" -%>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>       <div class='my_container'>
>         <%= yield %>
>       </div>
>     </body>
>   </html>
> ```

2- In Controller (You must add option as `disposition: 'inline'` to open in new tab)

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "show",
        disposition: 'inline',
        stream: false,
        layout: 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

3 - Pdf html doc name should end with `.erb` i .e `app/views/app/letters/show.pdf.erb`

```
<div>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```